# Laravel Route outside of main app

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

How can I do a laravel route on an external folder?

This is what I mean:

I have my main app pointing to `mysite.com/myapp`

So all my routes are like `mysite.com/myapp/something`
and the route is

```
Route::get('something',['uses'=>'someController@index']);
```

but I have a folder on `mysite.com/subdomain` which is accessed through `subdomain.mysite.com`

and I would like to create routes there too so i can access them as `subdomain.mysite.com/abc/def` with something like

```
Route::get('../subdomain/abc/{$someVariable}',['uses'=>'someController@someFunction']);
```

let me know if this makes sense and is possible in any way, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel is not necessary to create a subfolder to do subdomain routes.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing
**You can do**

```
Route::domain('subdomain.mysite.com')->group(function () {
    // subdomain.mysite.com/abc/def
    Route::get('abc/{someVariable}', 'someController@someFunction');
});
```

If you want to define routes into a file that is not the routes.php you can include_once into routes.php or include into a [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#routes)

Comment: just to extend the answer, 
1. I pointed my subdomain to the main app folder.
2. I wrapped the rest of routes that I had in `Route::domain('mysite.com')->group(function(){ /* all the routes here */});`